# socket_listen() ignores 'backlog' parameter, how to set connections limit then?

Tags: php, sockets

From the manual:

> The maximum number passed to the backlog parameter highly depends on
>   the underlying platform. On Linux, it is silently truncated to
>   SOMAXCONN. On win32, if passed SOMAXCONN, the underlying service
>   provider responsible for the socket will set the backlog to a maximum
>   reasonable value. There is no standard provision to find out the
>   actual backlog value on this platform.

Hell, what if I still want to limit connections myself? Limiting connections like:

```
if( count($client_sockets) < $max_clients ) {
    //accept connection
} else {
    echo "Limit reached!";
}
```

will not work well in combination with `socket_select()`, because function still got incoming connection, that server needs to handle properly! Accepting connection > `$max_clients` and than closing it right away is not an option, so... Maybe anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From another post I've understood that this is actually acceptable to allow connection and than close it, if it does not match required conditions. So scheme for multi-connection socket server would be:

1. `socket_accept()` for incoming connection, for `socket_select()` to handle it properly so server would not bother with it anymore;
2. Check required conditions match, such as: connections limit, allowed address, or your custom tokens;
3. If something is wrong, `socket_close()` this particular connection and delete it from the array of clients (or whatever else you might use for such purposes).

Maybe it will help someone.